# Shell script - getting cpu usage (%cpu) and storing it into a variable

Tags: shell, terminal

I am trying to retrieve the cpu usage (%cpu) of a process and store it into a variable.
I am able to display the %cpu and the command using Shell script:

```
echo Enter the process name you wish to fetch:
read pn
#Displays %cpu of process
ps -eo %cpu,command | grep $pn
```

Output:

```
Enter the process name you wish to fetch:
terminal
0.0 grep terminal
```

'0.0' defines the %cpu and 'grep terminal' defines the command (process).

How can I put the value of the cpu usage (%cpu) into a variable as such:

```
declare -x cpuUsage=[%cpu of process]
echo $cpuUsage
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure `0.0 grep terminal` is outputting what you want.  See this [question and its answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37508/in-what-order-do-piped-commands-run) for some background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like this to store the usage value in a variable:

```
echo Enter the process name you wish to fetch:
read pn
cpuusage=`ps -eo %cpu,command | grep $pn | grep -v grep | head -n 1 | sed 's,^ *,,' | cut -d ' ' -f 1`
echo $cpuusage
```

Be aware that if many processes matches the given name it simply takes the first returned by the ps output.

Comment: It works very well:) Thank you. Can you please tell me what the `sed` command does?

Comment: the sed command trims only the leading whitespace that is present when the cpu usage is below 100% and interferes with the following cut command which uses the space character as a delimiter